# Flip Animation not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, animation, uiview

I have a Custom view. This custom view has two UIImageViews - imageview1 and imageview2.

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.00];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(transitionDidStop:finished:context:)];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self cache:YES];
    if(frontVisible) {
        [imageview1 removeFromSuperview];
        [self addSubview: imageview2];
    }
    else {
        [imageview2 removeFromSuperview];
        [self addSubview: imageview1];
    }
    frontVisible = !frontVisible;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

---

The image changes from imageview1 to imageview2 and viceversa but I dont get the flip effect. Instead I see the fading out of one image as the other appears.

Comment: are you testing on the device or simulator?

Comment: I am testing on the simulator

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure but I checked the documentation and found this:

> **Discussion**
>
> If you want to change the appearance of a view during a transition—for example, flip from one view to another—then use a container view, an instance of UIView, as follows:
>
> 1. Begin an animation block.
> 2. Set the transition on the container view.
> 3. Remove the subview from the container view.
> 4. Add the new subview to the container view.
> 5. Commit the animation block.

So it says you have to create a container view in order to make it work properly.

Comment: I do get the flip now when I use UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft. (I don't how I got this working.)
But if I change the transition to UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp I still see that one of the images fades out as the other appears.
I am not able to understand what is so special with CurlUp

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're not getting the curl transition to work is because the curl transition does not work in the simulator.  It shows up as a fade instead.